# Issues with "git push heroku master"

Tags: git, heroku

I began taking up Heroku again, but have had some problems trying to get it to where I could upload an app to my server. I have taken the steps already to have the Heroku gem properly installed and both Sinatra and Ruby installed onto my Mac. Since I have been away from it for a while, I did these steps:

```
gem remote rm heroku
gem remote add heroku git@heroku.com:pxlc.git
cd Desktop/myapp
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push heroku master
```

After that I get this strange error telling me to do a "git pull". Shouldn't I have been able to put in my .ssh key and Heroku credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error telling you to do a pull is telling you that you can't push in your current state because you'd overwrite some other work that's been pushed to the git remote. You first have to pull to merge the remote changes into your local code, then push. It looks like you're creating brand new repo and trying to push it somewhere where something already exists.

**Edit:** To do what it's telling you, just `git pull heroku master`. It will fetch all the remote changes and merge them into your branch for you. This could fail with merge conflicts, which you'd then have to resolve. If it's successful, there's nothing else to do.

If you really do want to wipe out anything that's there--as in lost forever wipe out--you can `git push -f heroku master` to force the push.

Comment: How do I exactly pull and then merge?

Comment: If I get rid of everything, will I be able to start over with my application?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about heroku. I'm just telling you what's going on with git. Why don't you first take a step back and try cloning what's there into a new project directory with `git clone git@heroku.com:pxlc.git`? Then you can look over it and decide what you want to do: work from the existing code or wipe it out and start over or something in between.

Comment: if you know your local code works fine and you're happy to loose what ever is on Heroku a git push -f heroku master will work fine.

Comment: @John: From his question, his "local code" is a brand new, empty repo. That's why I'm not sure just pushing it is what he wants.

Comment: I was able to resolve all of this by removing the repo with "git remote rm heroku" and re adding with "git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:pxlc.git".

Answer (score 0):

the heroku steps confuse me too
for a pristine new project

init,commit,
THEN
git remote add heroku=>the git address given by heroku command
THEN push

i get stuck often
so
 i like to add it directly to .git/config file myself)

if heroku is at -1 (no history)
there should be no issue pushing your git repo (along with yr history) to heroku side